# when deleting cluodformation ` is invalid or cannot be assumed`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have error like this

```
Role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/cdk-xxxxxxxxp-northeast-1 is invalid or cannot be assumed
```

OK, so I made the role with `AdministratorAccess`

and same name

`cdk-stagcdk-cfxxxxxxxxxxxx-northeast-1`

However same error happens.

nnnn... I have no clue to do anything more.

Does anyone help?

My procedure to make role is here below.

create policy -> AWS account -> add AdministratorAccess -> then set the same name `cdk-stagcdk-cxxxxxx-ap-northeast-1`

**Solution**

`role` don't have trust policy,

So I changed the trust policy like this below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

thanks to @Marcin

Comment: What is the thrust policy on the role?

Comment: oooo it has trust policy from root only. so I changed {
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
   },
   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
   "Condition": {}
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Please don't use `*` as principal. THis allows everyone to assume your rule.

Comment: Yes, thank you this is just temporary and delete role soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you delete the bootstrap stack. Simply re-bootstrap the environment with `cdk bootstrap` and it will create the necessary roles.

Comment: Ah ,  I manually made the role and change the trust policy solved this problem but, It's quite useful that bootstrap works for this situation.